# Labelling Logarithmic Axes in steema teechart c#

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

I am using a logarithmic axis scale, the major tick marks are at 1, 10, 100,...  and labelled this way on the plot. But I would desperately like some of the minor tick marks to also be labelled. For example, I would like labels at 200 and 500 mbar.

Is it possible with `steema tchart and c#`

Comment: Please could you post your question here rather than link to it? Links have a habit of disappearing over time :)

Answer (score 2):

In your installation folder of TeeChart there is an example demo you can run which contains the answer you're looking for:

%PROGRAMFILES%\Steema Software\Steema TeeChart for .NET 2014 Evaluation 4.1.2014.02245\Examples\DemoProject\bin\ExecutableDemo\TeeChartNetExamples.exe

The demo in question is under:
All Features tab -> Welcome !\Axes\Labels\Custom logarithmic axis

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in wrapper written on teechart component. Teechart compenents logarithmic scale works fine.